# I have a hangman game I'm making, and I need help figuring out why it's not fully working

Tags: c++

I'm making a hangman game in C++ and I am close to finishing, however I have one major issue. I have to get the game to only allow the user 4 guesses, but my program doesn't register the correct number of guesses.

I've tried to change variables as well as the conditions within the if and else statements regarding guessing.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
cout << "Welcome to hangman!" << endl;

char choice = 'y';

while (choice == 'y') {
    string word;
    cout << "Enter a word to guess: ";
    getline(cin, word);

    if (word.empty()) {
        cout << "The word should not be blank.\n";
        continue;
    }

    bool contain_space = false;
    for (char c : word) {
        if (isspace(c)) {
            contain_space = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (contain_space) {
        cout << "The word cannot contain spaces.\n";
        continue;
    }

    vector <bool> index;
    for (int i = 0; i < word.size(); i++) {
        index.push_back(false);
    }

    **int guess_correct = 0;**
    int guess_wrong = 4;
    char letter;

    while (guess_wrong >= 0 && guess_correct < word.size()) {
        bool valid_guess = true;
        cout << "Guess a letter." << endl;
        cin >> letter;
        for (int i = 0;i < word.size(); i++) {
            if (word[i] == letter) {
                valid_guess = true;
                index[i] = true;
                guess_correct++;
                break;

            }
            else {
                guess_wrong = guess_wrong - 1;
            }

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < word.size(); i++) {
            if (index[i] == true) {
                cout << word[i] << "\t";
            }
            else {
                cout << "___\t";
            }
        }
        cout << endl;
    }


    cout << "Would you like to play again? (y/n)" << endl;
    cin >> choice;
    cin.ignore();
}
return 0;
}
```

The black ticks show the beginning of the code section I'm stuck on. Each time I run it, it will let me go through the game with correct guesses, but incorrect guesses don't allow for 4.

Comment: `bool valid_guess = true;` you probably want to initialize this to false instead. And if it is still false after your `for (int i = 0;i < word.size(); i++) { }` then and only then decrement `guess_wrong`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are decrementing `guess_wrong` for each letter in the word that doesn't match, not once for the "whole guess".

you probably want to move the `guess_wrong = guess_wrong - 1; // aka guess_wrong--` out of the for loop and only do it `if (!valid_guess)`.